# DWR - Classes Null

Tags: java, ajax, framework, injeção-de-dependência, instanciar-objeto

Caros

Estou com problemas ao injetar as classes ao chamar alguns metodos utilizando DWR com Hibernate.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
@Controller
@Transactional
public class ManterArvoreClassificacaoController {

    @Autowired
    private ArvoreClassificacaoService acs;

    @Autowired
    private AreaArvoreClassificacaoService aacs;

    @Autowired
    private AreaService areaService;

    @Autowired
    private ArvoreSubClassificacaoService ascs;




    public List<ArvoreClassificacao> listarArvoresArea(Area area) {
        return acs.listarArvoresArea(area);
    }
```

Comment: 1) Sua classe `ArvoreClassificacaoService` é de fato um _bean_ (está anotada com `@Service`)? 2) Essa classe está num pacote abaixo da classe que possui o método `main()` da sua aplicação? 3) Os outros _beans_ desse _controller_ funcionam ou também estão nulos?

Comment: @StatelessDev, o service esta marcado como <@Service>.
Minha aplicação não tem método Main(), é uma aplicação web.

Comment: Se você está usando Spring Boot, você tem uma classe anotada com, pelo menos, `@SpringBootApplication` e, dentro dela, um método `main()`. É referente a essa classe que lhe perguntei e que deve estar num pacote acima de todos os demais, para que o Spring possa corretamente escanear suas classes e criar _beans_. Se isso não é seguido, seus _beans_ não são escaneados, não são criados e isso pode ser o motivo de suas injeções estarem nulas.

Comment: Estou utilizando Spring MVC